# Probability in a rock paper scissor game

Tags: probability, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, recurrence-relations, markov-chains

I have the following question

In "Rock-Paper-Scissors", Tom uses the following strategy

If Tom most recently played Rock, then he is **equally likely** to choose any of the three strategies the next time he plays.

If Tom most recently played Paper, then the next time he plays he is **twice as likely** to play Scissors as he is to play Paper, and **twice as likely** to play Rock as he is to play Scissors.

Tom never plays Scissors twice. So, if he last played Scissors, he chooses either Rock or Paper, and in this case is **three times as likely** to play Paper.

Here's what I have tried

If ***Rock*** is played recently, then next move is $$\frac{1}{3} Rock \quad \frac{1}{3}Paper \quad \frac{1}{3}Scissor$$

If ***Paper*** is played recently, then next move is $$\frac{4}{7}Rock \quad \frac{1}{7}Paper \quad \frac{2}{7}Scissor$$

If ***Scissor*** is played recently, then next move is $$\frac{1}{4}Rock \quad \frac{3}{4}Paper \quad 0 Scissor$$

Find the dominant eigenvalue of the following matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{3} & \frac{4}{7} & \frac{1}{4} \\ \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{3}{4} \\ \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{7} & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

And I got $\lambda = 1$, the corresponding dominant eigenvector is then $\begin{bmatrix} \frac{27}{16} \\ \frac{49}{32} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Therefore, the probability of playing rock, paper and scissors should be $\frac{54}{135} \quad \frac{49}{135} \quad \frac{32}{135}$, respectively.

However, my answer was wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think your answer is wrong?

Comment: Well it's an online practice, so when I enter the answer, the feedback says I am wrong

Comment: That is the stable distribution for that transition matrix (personally I would transpose everything but that is a convention that makes no difference)

Comment: Note that the first component of your answer reduces to $2/5$.

Comment: How did you get the eigenvectors and proceeded from there.... If I attempt I'll be getting $3$ matrix with each corresponding to rock, paper or scissor as recently played

Comment: @Sirou Ewei: As Henry noted, you computed the _limiting_ probabilities. Is that what you were asked to compute?

Comment: @quasi Yes, I am required to compute the limiting probabilities. I followed lecture and thought the above is what I am supposed to do.

Comment: @Aderinsola Joshua I am just following the lecture. Maybe I am not completely comprehending the concept.

Comment: @Sirou Ewei: The limiting probabilities that you computed are correct.

Comment: @Sirou Ewei: Perhaps try entering your answer using $2/5$ for the first component.

Comment: I tried that, still wrong. The question was about the likely outcome as Tom keeps playing over and over and over. So I assume this is asking the limiting probability. Perhaps there's an error in the question itself

Comment: @quasi Also, the feedback says the correct answer is Rock $\frac{24}{109}$, and Paper $\frac{49}{109}$. I redid my calculation multiple times but could not get these answers

Comment: @Sirou Ewei:  Your method is fine, and your results for the limiting probabilities are correct. If you do a simulation, it should closely match your results.